# Reportviewer Not Filling Data

Tags: vb.net, report-viewer2010

I have a reportviewer control on my program. It has been working and then I changed somethings that had nothing to do with it. I have this code else where in my program the only difference between this code and the other is the datasets. However, this one is not filling the data in the reportviewer. The data is in the datatable but it is not displaying on the report. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
'Shows Appropriate Batch Reports
Private Sub btnShowBatchReport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowBatchReport.Click
    Try
        'Get Dates for reports
        Dim todayDate As Date = Today
        Dim weekDate As Date = Today.AddDays(-7)
        Dim monthDate As Date = Today.AddMonths(-1)
        Dim yearDate As Date = Today.AddYears(-1)
        Dim name As String = My.Settings.Store_Name

        'Assigning the report name object
        Dim BatchReportName As New Generic.List(Of ReportParameter)

        If rbBatchAll.Checked Then
            Me.OVERALLINVENTORYTableAdapter.Fill(Me.POSDataSet.OVERALLINVENTORY)
            BatchReportName.Add(New ReportParameter("ReportBatchName", "All Batches"))

        ElseIf rbBatchMonth.Checked Then
            Me.OVERALLINVENTORYTableAdapter.FillByBetweenDates(Me.POSDataSet.OVERALLINVENTORY, monthDate, todayDate)
            BatchReportName.Add(New ReportParameter("ReportBatchName", "Past Month Batches " & monthDate & " to " & todayDate))

        ElseIf rbBatchWeek.Checked Then
            Me.OVERALLINVENTORYTableAdapter.FillByBetweenDates(Me.POSDataSet.OVERALLINVENTORY, weekDate, todayDate)
            BatchReportName.Add(New ReportParameter("ReportBatchName", "Past Week Batches " & weekDate & " to " & todayDate))

        ElseIf rbBatchYear.Checked Then
            Me.OVERALLINVENTORYTableAdapter.FillByBetweenDates(Me.POSDataSet.OVERALLINVENTORY, yearDate, todayDate)
            BatchReportName.Add(New ReportParameter("ReportBatchName", "Past Year Batches " & yearDate & " to " & todayDate))

        Else
            Me.OVERALLINVENTORYTableAdapter.FillByBetweenDates(Me.POSDataSet.OVERALLINVENTORY, dpBatchStartDate.Value, dpBatchEndDate.Value)
            BatchReportName.Add(New ReportParameter("ReportBatchName", "Custom Batches between" & dpBatchStartDate.Value & " and " & dpBatchEndDate.Value))

        End If

        'Resets the Report Viewer
        rvBatchOrders.Reset()

        'Creates the ReportData Source Object
        Dim BatchOrders = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource

        'Assigns the DataSet to the object
        BatchOrders.Name = "InventoryBatch"


        'Assigns the binding source of the dataset
        BatchOrders.Value = INVENTORYBindingSource

        'Clears Previous Data source
        Me.rvBatchOrders.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()

        'Add the new data source
        Me.rvBatchOrders.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(BatchOrders)

        'Embeds the new report in the report viewer
        rvBatchOrders.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "POS_System_V2.OrderBatches.rdlc"

        'Sets the Report Name
        rvBatchOrders.LocalReport.SetParameters(BatchReportName)

        rvBatchOrders.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
        rvBatchOrders.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.PageWidth

        'Refreshs the report viewer with the new report
        rvBatchOrders.Refresh()
        rvBatchOrders.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It is funny, I bang myself over the head for 3 hours trying to fix this. Once I put it on stack overflow I immediately find the problem.

The Problem

```
 BatchOrders.Value = INVENTORYBindingSource
```

The Answer:

```
 BatchOrders.Value = OVERALLINVENTORYBindingSource
```

I had the wrong binding source.